# POST data is null

Tags: ninjaframework

I'm trying to post some data to the ninja framework. 
The posted data looks like `{"data":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]}` or a bit filled `{"data":[["028325166-2"],["aspernatur"],null,["Neotal","adipisci"],null,null,null,null]}` and should be a Array of Strings with the key 'data'.

I created a Data Transfer Object with is called FilterObject

```
public class FilterObject {

public FilterObject() {
}

public String[] data;

public String[] getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

}

This is my controller:

```
public Result filter(Context context, FilterObject object){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(object.data));
    return Results.ok();
}
```

The post is sent and no error thrown, but sadly the data-Array is empty! Do you have an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks right... You can try to replace String[] data with List<String> data... but that should not change anything... Are you sure the controller is called? And are you sure you are sending a proper request? Try sending the request with curl... what happens?

Comment: thanks for the answer, I actually worked around and used url parameter for filtering. I guess the request wasn't correct, but I couldn't find out why...